# publish over ftp jenkins plugin is not uploading subfolder

Tags: jenkins, ftp, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkinsfile that deploys my angular app code to a site using the Publish over FTP plugin. All of the files in the dist folder are transferred except an assets subfolder. I have tried putting in the following values for the sourceFiles parameter with no success: '`webapp/dist/', 'webapp/dist/**', 'webapp/dist/**/*'.`

Here is the publish over FTP part of my Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
                ftpPublisher paramPublish: null, masterNodeName:'', alwaysPublishFromMaster: true, continueOnError: false, failOnError: true, publishers: [
                    [configName: 'Angular app', verbose: true, transfers: [
                        [asciiMode: false, cleanRemote: true, makeEmptyDirs:true, excludes: '', flatten: false,
                        noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', 
                        remoteDirectory: "webapp", 
                        removePrefix: "webapp/dist",
                        remoteDirectorySDF: false, 
                        sourceFiles: 'webapp/dist/**/*']
                    ], usePromotionTimestamp: false, `enter code here`useWorkspaceInPromotion: false]
                ]
            }
        }
```

I've looked at the Publish over FTP pipeline documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-ftp/ and couldn't find anything parameters that I was missing. I'm stuck.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I wonder if it is just a specific asset folder if by chance you did not include it in the build by adding it to he angular.json file. When you run ng build --prod is the folder in the dist?

Comment: I haven't solved the issue yet. The assets folder does get created when I run ng build --prod.

Comment: I looked at my ftpPublisher and the only difference is I have makeEmptyDirs set to false. It shouldn't matter but maybe? Also does the ftp log show any errors? And if you log in with the same credentials used by ftpPublisher can you create subdirs?
And are there any other folders in the dist that get transferred?  
Another thing to check is if the asset folder is actually in the artifacts. I created a Jenkins Troubleshooting chat room if you want to troubleshoot there.

Comment: I went inside the Jenkins workspace folder and the assets subfolder isn't there. The assets subfolder is the only subfolder inside the dist folder. The only other file that doesn't get transferred is the favicon. I tried changing the sourceFiles parameter to 'webapp/dist/**'] with no success.

Comment: If it's not in the Jenkins workspace folders then it probably is not getting generated when you build. So i don't think changing sourcefiles is going to do anything. Can you please post the entire jenkins script and your package.json and angular.json? We can also continue this in chat (Jenkins room)

Comment: Hey, are there any spaces or special characters in your project folder structure in Jenkins?  Something like  workspace\my project\webapp\... Seems that there was a bug on some nodejs and angular cli versions under Jenkins. see this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. I changed the title of the pipeline to all lowercase letters without any spaces. I then changed the file path of the workspace folder to 'C:/jenkinsworkspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}' by modifying the workspaceDir entry in the config.xml located in the Jenkins root directory. I stopped the Jenkins service before modifying the config.xml. Both the assets folder and the favicon got generated in the build. It was one of the solutions mentioned in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9230. Thanks for your help @Alberto L. Bonfiglio.